Create a dynamic list of all worksheets in an Excel file (without VBA) which refreshes automatically when a new sheet is added
I have an Excel Workbook consisting of these sheets: 
Products, Brands, Projects, Overview

In the sheet Overview in Range A1:A4 I want to list the names of these sheets. 
Therefore, in the Name Manager I inserted the following:
List_of_Workbook = REPLACE(GET.WORKBOOK(1),1,FIND("]",GET.WORKBOOK(1)),"")

Afterwards in Cell A1 I inserted this formula:
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(List_of_Workbooks,))

The result looks like this:

All this works perfectly.

However, there are two issues with this solution:

I need to enable VBA Excel 4.0 macros. 
In case I add a new sheet I have to click into Cell A1 again to refresh the list. 

Is there solution which does not need VBA Excel 4.0 and refreshes the list automatically when a new sheet is added?

Look here: https://exceljet.net/formulas/list-sheet-names-with-formula#power_query_option
